# Ruby: How to return positive integer or 0 if number is negative?

Tags: ruby

I have a calculation that may return a negative value. In that case, I want to limit the lowest return value to 0.

```
a - b
> -1
```

To get the desired result, I know I can place that calculation in an array with `0` and retrieve the highest value:

```
[0, a - b].max
> 0
```

I thought that there was a method on Integer that could do this (I was thinking of `#floor` but that does something different.) I've taken a look at the documentation but I can't find a method that does what I want and I feel that I must have missed something. Is there a method that returns the result I want? Is there a better way than the one I've suggested?

Comment: Yep, `[0, a - b].max` is the most elegant I can think of right now.

Comment: Easy, `(a - b).to_s.sub(/-.*/, '0').to_i` (please don't)

Comment: There's [`clamp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp) but it requires both, a lower and an upper bound.

Comment: `a >= b ? (a-b) : 0` is really the only alternative (and it arguably reads better), but I think most Rubyists (other than @Marcin) would go with `[0, a-b].max`, though neither seem to me to be especially *elegant*.

Comment: `v.negative? ? 0 : v`

Comment: @Stefan You could `i.clamp(0, i.abs)` if you really want to use `clamp` but that feels a bit contrived and overly clever, shame that `clamp` doesn't take a range so you could `i.clamp(0..)` (in Ruby 2.6).

Comment: `(num+num.abs)/2`

Comment: `num.rect.max` if you're never using complex numbers. or `num.coerce(0).max`

Comment: @ Marcin Kołodziej :,(

Comment: If this were me, I'd do it in two lines: `v = a - b` and `v = 0 if v < 0`. It feels the most straight forward and I would probably put a comment above the second line explaining why I'm setting it to 0 if it's negative. I tend to put more weight in readability and less in code golfing. I would also recommend avoiding creating unnecessary arrays for performance reasons.

Comment: Be zero unless you are a natural number, just for :), `v = 0 unless (1..Float::INFINITY).include? v`, or `v = 0 unless v > 0`. But why all answering in comments?

Comment: See my solution to the original post this was marked a duplicate of.

I think your solution is essentially correct, and probably the most readable besides a small refactor.  I might change it slightly like so:
`def total  final_total = subtotal - discount;  [final_total, 0].max end`
Once you see this max expression once or twice you can read it as follows: "final_total, but at least zero".

See my solution to the original post this was marked a duplicate of.

Comment: @muistooshort _"shame that clamp doesn't take a range"_ – or keyword arguments, i.e. `clamp(min: 0)` ... maybe I should file a feature request.

Comment: @Stefan I was looking at the `cmp_clamp` source in `compar.c` yesterday to see what would be involved in patching it. I don't know if I could handle editing it without fixing the insane and inconsistent mess of mixed spaces and tabs and tabstops for the indentation.